# Gopro Live stream over WiFi pretty laggy

Tags: python, api, stream, gopro

I am trying to use the official GoPro API, using python, in order
to capture live stream from my GoPro Hero 3 Camera.

http://goprohero.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API/

I saw that when connected to GoPro wifi, stream is also available through an HTTP url : http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/aamba.m3u8

I opened this video stream through VLC, so I can watch it directly.
There is a pretty big latency (~5/6 seconds). The stream is also pretty laggy, it often crashes or lag.

How could I improve this ?
Someone already experienced GoPro python API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ffmpeg` with small `-probesize` (reduces analyzing duration and lowers the latency) and the lag would be reduced to under 2 seconds.

```
ffplay -probesize 32 "http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8"
```

by the way as far as I know there is no official GoPro API and all these libraries are provided by community (the one you are using is written by [Josh Villbrandt](https://github.com/joshvillbrandt).